# Writing a generic clone method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is there a way for a class to refer to its constructor in a way that works when it is subclassed?

```
abstract class Base<T> {
  constructor(readonly value: T) {}

  abstract getName(): string;

  clone() {
    const Cls = this.constructor;
    return new Cls(this.value);
  }
}
```

In this snippet, `Cls` is given the type `Function` and so the compiler complains that: "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typescript does not use a strict type for the constructor (it just uses `Function`) and since this is not a constructor, it is not callable with `new`.

The simple solution is to use a type assertion:

```
abstract class Base<T> {
    constructor(readonly value: T) { }

    abstract getName(): string;

    clone() {
        // Using polymorphic this ensures the return type is correct in derived  types
        const Cls = this.constructor as new (value: T) => this;
        return new Cls(this.value);
    }
}
```