# Get polymorphic reference to the class in a method

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have a very simple class with a (non-static) method that returns a new instance of that class:

```js
class Foo {
  makesAnother () {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

How do I make it properly polymorphic so that in subclasses `makesAnother` returns an instance of *that* class?

```js
class Bar extends Foo {}
const bar = new Bar()
bar.makesAnother() // is a Foo! Should be a Bar!
```

I tried this

```js
class Foo {
  makesAnother () {
    const Ctor = this.constructor;
    return new Ctor();
  }
}
```

this fails because the type of `this.constructor` is `Function`, which doesn't have a call signature. How do I construct a new instance of the class without concretely specifying in the method?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oFswGsCmEAggHbwAuAFngE7QAUAlCuhtMPMRGdAMJny0AvNEoBLCADp2nMtQCuwftQDcLDNTxk51YtGJ4A7ryWNVGAL6pLqVEA)

Comment: I voted to close on the wrong one, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56325751/1426891) might be the real dupe.

Comment: @JeffBowman ugh I swear that I googled that exact question title as a search string. Le sigh.